# Jmeter Response 500 internal server error for request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, internal-server-error, jmeter-5.0

HI everyone I need a help regarding to fix the 500 internal server error

Please check my below attached requests and correlation and response image

Please tell me if I was wrong in anywhere I keep trying to do the scripts to run and the result was 500 error.

**Redirect request:**

[image]

**Https request1:**

[image]

**Data correlation:**

[image]

**Passing parameters:**

[image]

**Sending request details:**

[image]

**Response message:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header of your request it appears that you should be sending a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) while you're sending parameters in form of [name-value pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair)

I think you should switch to `Body Data` tab in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put your parameters there like:

[image]

Also double check your [API contract](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-API-contract-and-who-should-create-it-when-building-a-set-of-APIs), it might be the case you need to change the method to [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

More information: [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)

Comment: @ Dmitri T thanks for the response as i checked the API its only GET request . and i  was checking with browser devloper tools to monitor the http request.Request URL: https://url/NZePS/api/GetFirstPageData?encryptedRequest=7AD4E14F49E693CAA27F724A2E9CF37BBC0A94511A5A5C0A196899FED213C6885F56C72E15FF189945A1F0A196C80B6A3BE282AECFE496F3521B9FEECFC87E2FCD34C9DD1BC37F63ED7E58AFBF4E8F580A6A64D55D82F66E84881268C47A30D6F803360CE489665F785435A6AF0EF190&mac=B9DF36F87AAE83E0D35D93C1135F17E01C1CC251&expiry=000001694F2A4A8F
Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK ......... this tell url with parameters